# Can you function both sides of an equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

So i had this question on my exam recently:
Given that: $g(x)= x +\ln x -1$ , $x>0$ ,(obviously $g$ is $1:1$)
$f(f(x))= f(x) + x + \ln x -1$   (1) , true for every $x>0$
prove that:

1. $f$ is $1:1$ (which i easily proved with monotony , no problem here)
2. $f^{-1}(1) = 1$
3. the equation $f(x) = x$ , $x>0$ is only true for $x=1$

so here's how i tackled the third one: $f(x) = x \Leftrightarrow f(f(x)) = f(x) \Leftrightarrow f(f(x)) - f(x) = 0 $
from (1): $ x + \ln x -1 = 0 \Leftrightarrow g(x) =0 \Leftrightarrow g(x) = g(1) \Leftrightarrow x=1$ since $g$ is $1:1$
so the equation is true for $x=1$, and since $f$ is monotonous ( or $1:1$) $x=1$ is the only root of the equation

My professor said that this solution is false because " I cannot function both sides of an equation because the equation is not true for all $x\in Df$" . I really don't see how what my professor said is relevant at all and I'm honestly really confused. Any ideas?

EDIT: I asked my professor again and it seems that his real problem was that, according to him, i cannot function an equation that might not have a solution to begin with. I disagree with that observation because even if the equation is not true for all x>0 , provided everything in my solution is equivalent to each other, the equation will just turn out to be impossible. I also showed my solution to two other professors at my school and they agreed with it.

Comment: This is hard to read, formatting it properly would help.  That said, it simply isn't true that $f(x)=x\iff f(f(x))=f(x)$ as the latter only applies to values in the range of $f(x)$.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.

Comment: I honestly had no idea i had to format it, I'm new here sorry about that. May i ask what you mean by '' it applies only to value sin the range of f(x) '' ?

Comment: That was a typo for "values in"  (it has since been corrected).  to the math:  Say $f(x)$ is $1$ if $x$ is rational and $0$ otherwise.  Then $f(f(x))=f(x)$ for all rationals.  But it is not true that $f(x)=x$ for all rationals.  Formatting is crucial:  it helps your readers get at your question quickly and it helps us preserve a permanent, easily searched record (which really is the point of the site).

Comment: I think you don't actually **need** the implications to run bidirectionally in your proof, but you are probably expected to keep track of the fact that the argument of $f$ is positive, similar to the way this is noted in statement (3). For example, instead of $f(x) = x \Leftrightarrow f(f(x)) = f(x)$ you could write $f(x) = x, x>0 \implies f(f(x)) = f(x), f(x)>0, x>0.$ The reverse implication is $x=1\implies f(x)=x,x>0$ which you prove by evaluating $f(1).$ @lulu, what do you think?

Comment: @lulu but here $f$ is injective unlike your example, and so has a left inverse $g$ which can be applied to the second equation to get $f(x) = x$.

Comment: @Uro  Sure, but that requires proof.  I wouldn't accept the claim on a stand alone basis.  Not in an exercise which called for a properly argued proof.

Comment: @lulu the proof is asked from question 1).

Comment: @Uro  There's no indication that the OP sees those two claims as related.  Indeed, the OP indicated that they couldn't see any relevance at all to the professor's objection. But, yes.  It is certainly possible to fill the gaps in the OP's argument.

Comment: @lulu so from what i understand if i had set f(x) to be positive for this particular equation the proof would be valid? I know that its not always possible to go backwards but in this particular situation since f is injective isnt the proof still valid?

Comment: I still don't quite see how there would be a situation like this where i wouldn't be able to function both sides

Comment: My point (and I expect this is the professor's point as well):  you need to prove that the two claims are equivalent.  This is, in fact, true but it is not true for all functions (I gave you a counterexample). Yes, it is true that it is true for  all injective functions, but you need to include the proof of that.  I suggest:  write out that argument, show it to your instructor, and ask if this settles his objection.

Comment: I didn't write that in my proof because the exercise had already required me to prove that f is 1:1 in the 1st question. I will ask him if me not mentioning that fact in my proof was the issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For reference the explanation he gave me was that in the same way i cannot apply limits to an equation i cannot function it, which to me sound like 2 completely separate situations. Obviously you cannot apply limits because the equation might not even be true for any x close to the point of the limit. The same cannot be said for functioning an equation. Completely separate circumstances

Comment: For the forward direction, it seems to me that condition (1) tells us that both $x$ and $f(x)$ are in the domain of $f$ for every $x>0.$

Answer (score 1):

First, let me present a solution for the question.

For the second part, observe that $f(f(1)) = f(1) + g(1) = f(1)$. Since f is one-to-one, $f^{-1}$ exist, so you can calculate $f^{-1}(f(f(x)))$ for $x=1$.

$$f^{-1}(f(f(1))) = f^{-1}(f(1)) = 1$$

For the last part, suppose, for absurd, that $f(x_0) = x_0$ for some $x_0 >0$ with  $x_0\neq 1$.

In this case, you have, for that:

$$f(f(x_0)) = f(x_0) + g(x_0)$$

$$f(x_0) = x_0 + g(x_0)$$

Which should be equal to $x_0$, by hypothesis. But, since $g(x)$ is one-to-one, $x_0 + g(x_0)  = x_0$ is true only if $g(x_0) = 0$, which implies that $x_0 = 1$, which contradict the condition that $x_0 \neq 1$.

Now, with respect the error of your solution and your question about the application of the function in both sides of an equation.

Consider  that you have the equality $g(x) = h(x)$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$. $f(g(x)) = f(h(x))$ only if $g(x) \in D_f$. Moreover, for this step $f$ don't even need to be one-to-one.

For better understand this step, think about equivalence:
Suppose that $g(x) = h(x)$ and $g(x)$ is in the domain of $f$. Then $f(g(x))$ exist, and, obviously, $f(g(x)) = f(g(x))$; now if you substitute $g(x)$ by $h(x)$ in the RHS, you will obtain $f(g(x)) = f(h(x))$.

Now, to "un-function"  some equation of $f$ (that is, the implication in the opposite way), you must apply the inverse of $f$, and, in this case, the LHS (or the RHS) of your equation must be in the domain of $f^{-1}$. That is, if $f(g(x)) = h(x)$, then $f^{-1}(f(g(x))) = f^{-1}(h(x))$ (and, consequently, $g(x) = f^{-1}(h(x))$ ) only if f(g(x)) is in the domain of $f^{-1}$.

**EDIT:**

Back to your solution. Your chain of implication are not true. First, you should write the range of values of $x$ that you are considering in your equation. If you are considering all domain of $f$ in all sentences, then there is no problem in the three first implication $f(x) = x \iff f(f(x))=f(x) \iff f(f(x)) - f(x) = 0$. But notice that the last expression $f(f(x)) - f(x) = f(x) - f(x) = 0$, for all $x>0$, Which conflicts with the hypothesis that $f(f(x)) - f(x) = g(x)$. Is for that reason that your solution it is not correct.

You could fix it saying: let $S  = \{x : f(x) = x, for x>0\}$. Then say that, for every $x\in S$, $f(x) = x \iff f(f(x))=f(x)$. Following this direction, you will should be able to prove that $S = \{1\}$.

Comment: I can see how your counter example holds true, however in your scenario |x| is not one to one, unlike my question. If f is one to one, shouldn't i be able to "un-function"  an equation regardless?

Comment: Good point @konnosgaming. I will edit my answer to better respond your question.

Comment: "you cannot say that a false sentence implies in another one." On the contrary, a false sentence implies any true or false sentence you like. That is how mathematical implication works. I wonder if this was a point of confusion for the instructor.

Comment: You are correct, @DavidK. My argumentation it is wrong in this part. I will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that function composition doesn't have to exist unless the domains and ranges are correct. For example if I consider a function between arbitrary sets $A$ and $B$ then $f:A \rightarrow B$ there is no assurance that $f \circ f$ exists. In fact it will only exist if the image $f(A) \subset A$. In this case since the range is $\mathbb{R}$ but the domain is only when $x>0$ and $\mathbb{R}$ is not a subset of the positive reals. This means $f(f(x))$ is not well-defined so you can't function both sides of the equation. Note that the composition being well-defined has nothing to do with being one-to-one, it's a consideration all on its own.

Comment: If you take a look at relation (1) , since the domain is x>0 and the relation is true for all x>0 since fof exists in relation (1) , f(x) must be positive for all x>0, otherwise the relation would be false to begin with. Hence the range cannot include all of the real numbers and is instead all of the positive numbers

Comment: @konnosgaming no, it's not. For example $f(1/2)<0$ and so $f(f(1/2))$ doesn't exist. The image is the entire real numbers, not just the positive reals. That's the problem.

Comment: How exactly did you calculate that f(1/2) <0 ? Am i missing something?

Comment: @konnosgaming note that $(1/2)-1 < 0$ and $\ln (1/2) < 0$, so their sum is strictly negative.

Comment: That is function g you're referring to, not f